# Absolute Iframe URL issue

Tags: html, audio

I will admit I'm very unfamiliar with html - I've only really worked with object-oriented programming and not markup languages.

I'm working on audio controls for a website for someone else, I feel like I understand how the control tag itself works, but I cannot make the urls I link or function in audio players. I think it's the because of how I'm uploading the files, but I don't know if a website directly uploads the files. (I've tried using dropbox/google drive, but I don't think I can get the link I would need for that.)
Because of requests from the employer I'm working through go-daddy's iframe and not creating from scratch if that is relevant.

The upper line is my attempt at writing audio controls, the second controls are just an example I've been trying to mimic.

[Code in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YARfi.png)

Comment: please paste code in question instead of screencap ! can you edit your question ? `thanks

Comment: i think you can't link directly to dropbox, try putting the file elsewhere, closer to your html file